# How can I configure Drupal to send out Last Modified/Etag headers

Tags: caching, drupal, etags

I am trying to get our Drupal 8.x website to send out ETag headers and/or Last-Modified headers for our pages, so that client browsers (and CloudFlare's intermediary cache) will cache the page. 
However, when I manually set the ETag headers, they seem to be removed by drupal.
I have enabled Drupal's caching mechanism and upped max age to 1 day. Still I never get Drupal to send out these ETag and Last-Modified headers.

Anyone got a hint on where to look at? I cannot find proper documentation on this.

Comment: HOw do you *manually set the ETag headers* ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I think it may still be relevant as I've come across this issue in both D7 and and D8.  In my investigation and research, I have found these two links addressing this issue in the DO community.  Hopefully, it may help someone else.

D8 - https://www.drupal.org/project/lastmodified_since
D7 - https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3055984

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29852621)